# How to do a background job in React Native for Android 8.1 (Oreo)

Tags: react-native

I have written code for retrieving notifications from server using react-native-background-job in case the app is in background or has been killed. The code is working on all other versions of Android, but it is not working on Android 8.1. It is not running and also throwing a pop up notification "your app has closed, start again, send feedback". I know that this is because of the restriction put by Oreo on execution limits of the background running of apps. What changes should I make my code to make it run on Android 8.1 too?

```
const regularJobKey = 'regularJobKey';

let uid = 0; let id = 0;  

const checking = () => {
    axios.get('/getmessagecount').then(response => {
        ...
    });
};  

BackgroundJob.register({    
    jobKey: regularJobKey,  
    job: () => checking()  
});

export default class App extends Component {      
    componentWillMount = () => {     
        BackgroundJob.schedule({  
            jobKey: regularJobKey,  
            period: 20000,  
            alwaysRunning: true  
        });  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of this problem here-> https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job/commit/dd20672c6719a2eb4739161ee1f52386c4fa0f70?diff=split